# how to make componentDidMount() to finish before rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How do I make the page to render after componentDidMount finish.

All similar questions asked on here are given a solution that is specifically related to their problem

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {

  region: {
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
}
  }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
   this.getMyLocation();
 };

getMyLocation = () => {

 navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
   (position) => {

    const region = {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      };
    this.setState({
      region: region
    })

   }
 );
}

render(){

<MapView
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  initialRegion={this.state.region}
  style = {styles.container}
  followUserLocation = {true}
  showsUserLocation = {true}

  ref="map"
  >

  </MapView>

 }
```

I was expecting the `initialregion` to be centered at the current user location but it instead is centered at `latitude:0`, `longtuide:0` which is originally set under constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `initialRegion` prop of your `MapView` can only be set once when the MapView component is constructed, in that case you should only render it when your location data is available. so you may change your render function to be something like.

```
render() {
  return this.state.region ? <MapView ... /> : <LoadingIndicator />;
}
```

And initialize your `state.region` to be `null` in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can move getMyLocation() to constructor

Try this way

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.getMyLocation();  
}
```

The Rule of function calling flow is:

```
1. Reducer functions called
2. Constructor called 
3. Render () called
4. ComponentDidMount() called
```